# Insert data from Oracle to griddb

Tags: oracle-apex, database-migration, griddb

I want to use open source db called griddb. Basically optimised for IOT devices. I want to create and use it for developing   An application for IOT devices in smart home setup to store data and define automations. I'm interested to know how to insert data from my existing Oracle database to Griddb. The application is an apex application want to consume data into it using APIs from griddb.

Exactly how to approach it ?

I have configured the instance of griddb and tried inserting data that works but not able to understand migrating the data from Oracle database.